# Jquery Quicksand filter + prettyphoto not working after ajax loading content

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, lightbox, quicksand

I'm testing quicksand script  to filter some image.

I had implemented the script with some image [DEMO HERE](http://www.hostingcubo.com/quicktest.php). 
As you can see there are circle, pentagon and triangle with different color.  
The filter are working fine thanks to this inline script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    (function($) {
        $.fn.sorted = function(customOptions) {
            var options = {
                reversed: false,
                by: function(a) {
                    return a.text();
                }
            };
            $.extend(options, customOptions);

            $data = $(this);
            arr = $data.get();
            arr.sort(function(a, b) {

                var valA = options.by($(a));
                var valB = options.by($(b));
                if (options.reversed) {
                    return (valA < valB) ? 1 : (valA > valB) ? -1 : 0;              
                } else {        
                    return (valA < valB) ? -1 : (valA > valB) ? 1 : 0;  
                }
            });
            return $(arr);
        };

    })(jQuery);

    $(function() {

      var read_button = function(class_names) {
        var r = {
          selected: false,
          type: 0
        };
        for (var i=0; i < class_names.length; i++) {
          if (class_names[i].indexOf('selected-') == 0) {
            r.selected = true;
          }
          if (class_names[i].indexOf('segment-') == 0) {
            r.segment = class_names[i].split('-')[1];
          }
        };
        return r;
      };

      var determine_sort = function($buttons) {
        var $selected = $buttons.parent().filter('[class*="selected-"]');
        return $selected.find('a').attr('data-value');
      };

      var determine_kind = function($buttons) {
        var $selected = $buttons.parent().filter('[class*="selected-"]');
        return $selected.find('a').attr('data-value');
      };

      var $preferences = {
        duration: 800,
        easing: 'easeInOutQuad',
        adjustHeight: false
      };

      var $list = $('#list');
      var $data = $list.clone();

      var $controls = $('ul.splitter ul');

      $controls.each(function(i) {

        var $control = $(this);
        var $buttons = $control.find('a');

        $buttons.bind('click', function(e) {

          var $button = $(this);
          var $button_container = $button.parent();
          var button_properties = read_button($button_container.attr('class').split(' '));      
          var selected = button_properties.selected;
          var button_segment = button_properties.segment;

          if (!selected) {

            $buttons.parent().removeClass('selected-0').removeClass('selected-1').removeClass('selected-2').removeClass('selected-3').removeClass('selected-4').removeClass('selected-5').removeClass('selected-6');
            $button_container.addClass('selected-' + button_segment);

            var sorting_type = determine_sort($controls.eq(1).find('a'));
            var sorting_kind = determine_kind($controls.eq(0).find('a'));

            if (sorting_kind == 'all') {
              var $filtered_data = $data.find('li');
            } else {
              var $filtered_data = $data.find('li.' + sorting_kind);
            }

            if (sorting_type == 'size') {
              var $sorted_data = $filtered_data.sorted({
                by: function(v) {
                  return parseFloat($(v).find('span.colore').text());
                }
              });
            } else {
              var $sorted_data = $filtered_data.sorted({
                by: function(v) {
                  return $(v).find('strong').text().toLowerCase();
                }
              });
            }

            $list.quicksand($sorted_data, $preferences);

          }

          e.preventDefault();
        });

      }); 

      var high_performance = true;  
      var $performance_container = $('#performance-toggle');
      var $original_html = $performance_container.html();

      $performance_container.find('a').live('click', function(e) {
        if (high_performance) {
          $preferences.useScaling = false;
          $performance_container.html('CSS3 scaling turned off. Try the demo again. <a href="#toggle">Reverse</a>.');
          high_performance = false;
        } else {
          $preferences.useScaling = true;
          $performance_container.html($original_html);
          high_performance = true;
        }
        e.preventDefault();
      });
    });
</script>
```

I had also included prettyphoto script for a lightbox effect.

The problem is that the prettyphoto script stop working after I use the filter.
I understand that this is caused by ajax reload content.  
I need to "reload" prettyphoto [as explained also on the prettyphoto official forum](http://forums.no-margin-for-errors.com/discussion/757/force-prettyphoto-to-refresh-when-content-changes-dynamically/p1)

I tried  with:

```
function reloadPrettyPhoto() {
$(".pp_pic_holder").remove();   
$(".pp_overlay").remove();
$(".ppt").remove();
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();

}
```

and I call the function around the line 112, after:

```
    $list.quicksand($sorted_data, $preferences);

      }
// Try to reload prettyphoto
reloadPrettyPhoto();
e.preventDefault();

    });
```

...naturally without results :(

I tried also with:

```
jQuery.ajaxStop(function(){
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
    });
```

But nothing.

I cannot understand how to use on my script.

```
jQuery.ajaxStop(function(){
// Code to be run.
});
```

as also a forum user recommend

Tnx in advance for your help!

Answer (score 7):

You indeed need to re-initialize prettyPhoto once quicksand had been executed.

I took you example page and modified that line:

```
$list.quicksand($sorted_data, $preferences);
```

To become:

```
$list.quicksand($sorted_data, $preferences, function(){ $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto(); });
```

This way, every time content is filtered, prettyPhoto will be refreshed.

You can see it working here: http://no-margin-for-errors.com/demos/quicksand/quicktest.html

Thanks

Comment: Wow Scaron! This is awesome! Tnx for your support!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried calling the prettyPhoto on the Quicksand callback?

Here is the example from the Quicksand website:

```
$('#source').quicksand( $('#destination li'), {
    name: value
}, function() {
    // callback code
});
```

I've had some good experience with Quicksand and doing other things along side it on [www.lovecreativity.co.uk](http://www.lovecreativity.co.uk) - see if that helps you out at all?

Good luck

Comment: Hello Tish! Tnx for your answer. I'm still stuck on this from 10 days shit :( I asked also on getacoder to pay a js expert to help me to solve the problem. Any results. I think that I shoud modify this part of the script around line 112  `code` }

            $list.quicksand($sorted_data, $preferences);

          }
`code`

Comment: But I don't know how to introduce a callback on this function. :/

Answer (score 0):

As scaron said, you should try replacing

```
$list.quicksand($sorted_data, $preferences);
```

with

```
$list.quicksand($sorted_data, $preferences, function(){ $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto(); });
```

AND in your code check that your rel attribute reads "prettyphoto" instead of "prettyPhoto", with a capital P, maybe it's just that?